# Image Type to save

Tags: c#, image

Which image type is good to save according to optimization, which take less size and good quality on disk.
I am saving a bitmap image and need to choose type i.e., png, jpeg

Comment: It depends on what type of image you're saving. JPEG is good for full color photographs where the loss of quality isn't noticeable, whereas PNG excels at things like screenshots and line drawings.

Comment: What research have you done already? There is extensive documentation available on the various image file formats. What _specifically_ are you trying to figure out, given what you've read so far?

Answer (score 4):

Depend on your purpose:

**PNG** format is a lossless compression file format, which makes it a common choice for use on the Web. **PNG** is a good choice for storing line drawings, text, and iconic graphics at a small file size.

**JPG** format is a lossy compressed file format. This makes it useful for storing photographs at a smaller size than a **BMP**. **JPG** is a common choice for use on the Web because it is **compressed**. For storing line drawings, text, and iconic graphics at a smaller file size, **PNG** are better choices because they are **lossless**. **JPGs don’t support transparency**

Comment: Thank You Liem... that's what i want short precise and to the point information.

Comment: i already did that :)